# CodeIgniter REST Api log on separated DB 20 seconds more

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I have a REST Api Codeigniter server which respond very well. 0.02 sec max per call.
I want to enable the logs but when i do it, responses take 20 more secondes. So 20.02 seconds for the same process.

I found that the time is lost in REST_Controller.php file at this line :
`$this->rest->db = $this->load->database($this->config->item('rest_database_group'), TRUE);`
When the rest DB is loaded.

My Database file have 2 DB records like this :

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    //'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => 'X.X.X.X',
    'username' => 'my_user',
    'password' => 'my_pass',
    'database' => 'my_database',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);

$db['rest'] = array(
    //'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => 'X.X.X.X',
    'username' => 'my_user',
    'password' => 'my_pass',
    'database' => 'my_database',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

And my config file have `$config['rest_database_group'] = 'rest';`

The log line is written in the rest database without any problems but 20 seconds more than without logs...

Any ideas?

Thks for your help.
David.

Answer (score 0):

Thks for your help. I found the solution.

There was a DNS Problem on my MySQL Server. Just talk with IP addresses is not enougth. I had to specify my Server's names in hosts files on each server.

The lag time of 20 seconds was on the MySQL SQL there was a login trying of a unauthenticated user from my server.

Problem is gone with DNS parms.

Bye !